# IE 11 not rendering a page properly

Tags: windows-server-2008, azure, internet-explorer-11

The URL I am trying to access: https://www.barchart.com/stocks/indices/russell/russell1000?viewName=performance&orderBy=percentChange1y&orderDir=asc

I am expecting a table to be displayed (seems be loaded using JavaScripts) but the page won't load completely and in fact page looks like crap.

```
IE Version: 11.0.9600.18534

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter 
OS Version:                6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Server
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
System Model:              Virtual Machine
System Type:               x64-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Intel64 Family 6 Model 63 Stepping 2 GenuineIntel ~2394 Mhz
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
Total Physical Memory:     768 MB
Available Physical Memory: 231 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  1,792 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 1,048 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    744 MB
```

If it counts - this VM where I am having this issue is hosted in Azure

[here is the image with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTYQw.png)

Comment: Without an image to show us what is wrong, it’s impossible to answer your question. This is a situation where a picture is worth more than a thousand words.  Being this is server 2008, are you sure you fully disabled internet explorer enhanced security configuration?

Comment: Issue is resolved - First reset security zones to defaults. The URL documented above sources javascripts from other sites like cloudfront, google etc, added all those https sites to Trusted sites list - now page is displaying correctly.